# Autowired dependencies failed

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I am facing an error telling autowired dependencies are failed. I tried all that I can do and I checked many forums and stackoverflow but I couldn't figure out what's going wrong in it.

I am attaching all the code including the stacktrace.

Stacktrace:

```
<Dec 22, 2016, 10:25:59,412 AM EST> <Error> <org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader> <BEA-000000> <Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService com.passwordmanager.myapp.HomeController.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService com.passwordmanager.myapp.HomeController.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Dec 22, 2016, 10:25:59,436 AM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService com.passwordmanager.myapp.HomeController.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService com.passwordmanager.myapp.HomeController.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService com.passwordmanager.myapp.HomeController.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO com.passwordmanager.service.LoginService.iLoginDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Dec 22, 2016, 10:25:59,466 AM EST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "261459827548032" for task "0" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Dec 22, 2016, 10:25:59,470 AM EST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 9 task for the application "PasswordManager_war_exploded" on [partition-name: DOMAIN].> 
<Dec 22, 2016, 10:25:59,477 AM EST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "PasswordManager_war_exploded".> 
<Dec 22, 2016, 10:25:59,477 AM EST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}:org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No matching bean of type [com.passwordmanager.dao.ILoginDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdemo" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
            <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />

        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.passwordmanager.myapp" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.passwordmanager.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.passwordmanager.dao" />

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="12"></beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

</beans:beans>
```

Homecontroller:

```
@Controller
class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String indexPage(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public ModelAndView userLogin() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
        //model.addObject("userName", name);
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/result", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public ModelAndView loginResult(@RequestParam Map<String,String> reqParms) {

        //LoginDetails loginDetails = new LoginDetails(reqParms.get("userName"), reqParms.get("userPassword"));


        String userName = reqParms.get("userName");
        String userPasswd = reqParms.get("userPassword");

        User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String name = user.getUsername();


        if(name.isEmpty()){
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
            return model;
        }
        else{
            LoginDetails result = loginService.findByUsername(userName, userPasswd);
            if(result != null) {
                System.out.println(result.getuserName());
                ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("loginResult");
                model.addObject("userName", name);
                return model;
            } else{
                ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
                return model;
            }
        }
    }
```

LoginService:

```
@Service
public class LoginService {

    @Autowired
    private ILoginDAO iLoginDAO;


    /*public LoginService(ILoginDAO iLoginDAO) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.iLoginDAO = iLoginDAO;
    }*/

    public LoginDetails findByUsername(String username, String userPasswd) {
        return iLoginDAO.findByUsername(username, userPasswd);
    }
}
```

ILoginDAO:

```
@Repository
public interface ILoginDAO extends CrudRepository<LoginDetails, Long> {

    @Query(" from LoginDetails as o where o.userName=:username and o.password = :userPasswd")
    LoginDetails findByUsername(String username, String userPasswd);

    //boolean checkLoginDetails(String username, String password);
    //boolean checkLoginDetails(String username, String password);


}
```

I cannot find an error on this. Can someone help me fixing it.

Comment: I think you are missing come configuration. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods Essentially you need to add `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories"/>` so an implementation is created by the framework.

Comment: @AlanHaySo, we do not write context:component-scan base-package? Instead we will just write jpa:repositories?

Comment: Yes. That should fix it.

Comment: Hi @AlanHay after adding the line you said I am getting the following error: 
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [servlet-context.xml]

Comment: Have you added the Jpa namespace to the xml

Comment: Yes I did put but I am still getting the error. The error that I have mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Please add following in your configuration,

Add `jpa:repositories` configuration to scan your `repository` package

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.passwordmanager.dao"/>
```

Also I would suggest to use `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository` if you are working with `ORM` with `JPA`.

If yes then update your `ILoginDAO` as

```
@Repository
public interface ILoginDAO extends JpaRepository<LoginDetails, Long> {
```

Also you can add `package` separated definitions in `component-scan`.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.passwordmanager.myapp" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.passwordmanager.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.passwordmanager.dao" />
```

Instead,

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.passwordmanager.myapp, com.passwordmanager.service, com.passwordmanager.dao" />
```

Comment: That didn't work to me. I am getting an new exception in my stack trace.

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.

Comment: @Vamsi now it seems your DAO is scanned. If this exception is after you changed to JpaRepository then please try with CrudEepository you had earlier and let me know

Comment: Its the same error. I guess I need to write persistance.xml but don't know how and what all will be there in it.
I am currently stuck at this point

Answer (score 0):

After much research I fixed this by adding entityManagerFactory, jpaVendorAdapter and transactionManager to my servlet-context.xml

Below is the code that I have added in order to make it work

```
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.vamsi.model" />
        <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="autoReconnect">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="profileSQL">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="characterEncoding">utf-8</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">NONE</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
```

The above code can also be written in persistance.xml